# concatenate columns and selecting some columns in Pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`

```
data = [
(1, 'a', '', 'b', '', 'c', '123_abc', 'sam', 'NY'),
(2, 'b', 'abc_123', 'd', '', 'e', '', 'Tim', 'NJ'),
(3, 'c', '', 'f', '', 'g', '', 'Jim', 'SFO')] 

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(["id", "abc_abled", "abc_serial", "bca_abled", "bca_serial", "cca_abled", "cca_serial", "name", "city"])



df
DataFrame[id: int, abc_abled: string, abc_serial: string, bca_abled: string, bca_serial: string, cca_abled: string, cca_serial: string, name: string, city: string]

df.show()

+---+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----+----+
| id|abc_abled|abc_serial|bca_abled|bca_serial|cca_abled|cca_serial|name|city|
+---+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----+----+
|  1|        a|      null|        b|      null|        c|   123_abc| sam|  NY|
|  2|        b|   abc_123|        d|      null|        e|      null| Tim|  NJ|
|  3|        c|      null|        f|      null|        g|      null| Jim| SFO|
+---+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----+----+
```

I want to create a new data frame by selecting the following columns and `concatenate certain column values`.

```
df1
DataFrame[id:int, serial_number: string, name:string, city:string]

df1.show()

+---+-------------+----------+
| id|serial_number|name| city|
+---+-------------+----------+
|  1|      123_abc| sam|   NY|
|  2|      abc_123| Tim|   NJ|
|  3|             | Jim|  SFO|
+---+-------------+----+-----+
```

Here `serial_number` will be `all columns that end with _serial` concatenated. `If the columns have null values ignore the values and concatenate other strings`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is get the array of column names that ends with `_serial`

```python
serialCols = [x for x in df.columns if str(x).endswith('_serial')]
```

Then use it with `concat_ws` *inbuilt function* to concat the column values in `select` expression as

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select(
    df['id'],
    f.concat_ws('', *serialCols).alias('serial_number'),
    df['name'],
    df['city']
).show(truncate=False)
```

Here I have used an *empty character* to concat the strings

so the above code should give you

```python
+---+-------------+----+----+
|id |serial_number|name|city|
+---+-------------+----+----+
|1  |123_abc      |sam |NY  |
|2  |abc_123      |Tim |NJ  |
|3  |             |Jim |SFO |
+---+-------------+----+----+
```

---

**Edit**: One could also use [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) in place of `concat_ws()`.